# strpos code then add value to title

Tags: php, strpos

I'm trying to get `strpos` working the way I want, but stumbled over a few problems here.

The deal is I want to add a text to the title, if the title includes a specific work.

My title is represented as:

```
<h4><?php echo $article->name; ?></h4>
```

Then I want to use a code like this:

```
$a = '$article->name';

if (strpos($a, 'banana') !== false) {
    echo 'is good';
}
```

However it it fails.

Does anyone know how I can get `$a` to read my title (which is a gode, not just a text)?

How do I replace the echo `is good` with a picture? (same issue here as my problem is that I dont understand how to get the code working withi the `''`). I know the `img src=""`, but just don't how to get it work in this code.

Comment: Remove the single quotes from `$a = '$article->name'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are having trouble with variable interpolation in strings. Always good to check what is in [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing).

Basically, if you use single quotes the characters will be taken literally. So, to interpret a variable value inside a string, use double quotes.

Additionally, there is obviously no need to interpolate a single value:

```
$a = "$article->name"; # not needed
$a = $article->name;   # better
```

And you can also concatenate values instead of interpolating them:

```
echo "<img src=\"$url\" />";
echo '<img src="' . $url . '" />';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
            $a = $article->name;

            if (strpos($a, 'banana') !== false) {
            echo 'is good';
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $a = $article->name;

    if (strpos($a, 'banana') !== false) {
        echo '<img src="'.$article->img.'"/>' ;
    }
```

Im assuming you have the adress of the image on the $article->img

And as others said you have to remove the single quotes in the first line.

Test like that:

```
    <h4>
    <?php $a = $article->name; if (strpos($a, 'elstock') !== false) { 
     $a .= 'is good';   
     }?>
    <?php echo $a; ?>
   </h4>
```

Comment: Thanks. I dont get the blank page (error) anymore. But the text dosen't add to the title, just looks like before.


   `<h4><?php echo $article->name; ?></h4><?php $a = $article->name; if (strpos($a, 'banana') !== false) { echo 'is good'; }?>`

Comment: @easyquestions you need to check if $article have the information that you want. var_dump($article);  and check

Comment: @easyquestions do you want the "is good" to appear inside the h4 tag? Is that it? If so, move the closing `</h4>` to after your PHP code.

Comment: Yes, it exists. But the ekstra tekst, in this case "is good" dont appear. So it still just says. bana, instead of banana is good. Tried to set he h4 around the whole article, but no difference. `<h4><?php echo $article->name; ?><?php $a = $article->name; if (strpos($a, 'elstock') !== false) { echo 'is good'; }?></h4>`

Comment: <h4>
        <?php $a = $article->name; if (strpos($a, 'elstock') !== false) {          $a .= 'is good'; }?>
        <?php echo $a; ?>
       </h4>

test like that

Answer (score 0):

I think get string value from the variable is problems.

```
$a = '$article->name'; 
Test like that:
<h4>
<?php 
    $a = $article->name; 
    if((strpos($a, "banana")) !== false){
        echo $a."is good";
    }
?>
</h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was complcated, I had to define the article as $title before I got this working...

```html
<?php $a = strtolower($title." ".$description['title']); if (strpos($a, 'bana') !== false) { echo ' is good'; } ?>
```